# Implement a ruler using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to implement a ruler in CSS that looks like this:

[image]

I was able to find something similar here: http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/kwcug/ but I can't figure out how to edit it to be the way I need it (number appearing above the line and having those lines like in the picture). This is the part of the css that handles it:

```
.ruler li {
    padding-left: 1cm;
    width: 2em;
    margin: .64em -1em -.64em;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px hsl(60, 60%, 84%);
}
.ruler li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: .64em;
    top: -.64em;
    right: 1em;
}
```

Can you please give me some hints?

Comment: Please revise to ask a more clear, specific question. Describe what aspect of the project is giving you trouble. General requests for help are off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach

```css
.ruler {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   margin: 4em 2em;
   height: 2em;
   padding: 0;
   color: #ddd;
   outline: 2px currentColor solid;
   outline-offset: -2px;

   counter-reset: cm ;
   width: max-content;
   font: .85em Arial;
}

.ruler::before {
   display: block;
   width: max-content;
   content: "0";
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 100%;
   left: 2px;
   transform: translate(-50%, -1em)
}


.ruler li::after {
   content: counter(cm);
   counter-increment: cm;
   display: block;
   width: max-content;
   overflow: visible;
   color: #ddd;
   text-align: right;
   transform: translate(50%, -1.5em);
}

.ruler li:nth-child(2n - 1)::after {
   color: transparent;
}


.ruler li {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   color: transparent;
   width: 1cm;
   height: calc(2px + 1.5em);
   transform: translate(0, -.75em);
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-left: 2px #ddd solid;
}

.ruler li:last-child {
   border-right: 2px #ddd solid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ruler">
   <li>0</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
   <li>9</li>
   <li>10</li>
</ul>


<ul class="ruler">
   <li>0</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
   <li>9</li>
   <li>10</li>
   <li>11</li>
   <li>12</li>
   <li>13</li>
   <li>14</li>
   <li>15</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this one help?

```css
.ruler {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 14px;
}

.ruler .cm,
.ruler .mm {
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
  height: 14px;
  width: 10%;
}

.ruler .cm:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  font: 11px/1 sans-serif;
}

.ruler .mm {
  height: 5px;
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(5) {
  height: 10px;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 0%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(1):after {
  content: "0";
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 10%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(2):after {
  content: "1";
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 20%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(3):after {
  content: "2";
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 30%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(4):after {
  content: "3";
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 40%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(5):after {
  content: "4";
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: 50%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(6):after {
  content: "5";
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(7) {
  left: 60%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(7):after {
  content: "6";
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(8) {
  left: 70%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(8):after {
  content: "7";
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(9) {
  left: 80%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(9):after {
  content: "8";
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(10) {
  left: 90%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(10):after {
  content: "9";
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(11) {
  left: 100%;
}

.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(11):after {
  content: "10";
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 10%;
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 20%;
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 30%;
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 40%;
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 50%;
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: 60%;
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(7) {
  left: 70%;
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(8) {
  left: 80%;
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(9) {
  left: 90%;
}

.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(10) {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='ruler'>
  <div class='cm'>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='cm'>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='cm'>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='cm'>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='cm'>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='cm'>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='cm'>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='cm'>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='cm'>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='cm'>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
    <div class='mm'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='cm'></div>
</div>
```